# Best way to restrict/manage PHP apps to use my postfix?

Tags: php, postfix, smtp, spam, imap

I want to allow PHP apps to send mail but under very restricted conditions.

And I don't want to allow sendmail-like command for PHP apps (I'm using chrooted PHP and it's too much headache), thus I disabled `mail()` function in PHP.

What options do I have to strictly allow/monitor PHP apps sending via my postfix?

- HELO name can be spoofed
- IP can be spoofed and it's not explicitly linked to a PHP app user

AUTH? Should I also require `smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch` ?

I already have a `smtpd` on port 587 running which uses `smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot` but I don't suppose a PHP app would ever have an account on Dovecot IMAP server - I suppose most PHP apps would send mail as 'noreply@'. Should I create another instance of `submission` in `/etc/postfix/master.cf` ?

Comment: Why use another instance of submission? You could just make a mail account that a PHP app could log in to.

Comment: I'm authenticating against IMAP right now. I don't see it makes sense to authenticate against IMAP for an account which will never be used for delivery - ie. never used for anything else then just authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to enable and force AUTH when sending.
Create one email address per domain.
Then tell the developers/webmaster that they have to use the given user+pass when sending ( and hopefully their PHP app supports SMTP with auth ). You have to disable unauthenticated mail relay from localhost ( in postfix ). And perhaps allow ( in firewall) outgoing smtp traffic only from postfix . Then maybe ratelimit the mails.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using OpenBSD so I did put this rule into my `/etc/pf.conf` to block connections on loopback interface for PHP users who have UID higher than 2000: `block return log (all, user, to pflog1) quick on lo0 proto tcp from any to any port = 25 user > 2000`. I was also trying to isolate PHP completely via rdomain but no success yet.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenBSD&pf, but are you sure you need to block on loopback? And not on ethernet?

Comment: I want PHP app talks to postfix running locally and thus it would reach loopback. I also block outgoing traffic to any port 25 for uid > 2000.

Comment: I suggested to block outgoing non postfix smtp traffic, because a compromised PHP site can behave as MTA, and send the mails/spam directly to remote mail servers ( like yahoo/gmail etc ), skipping postfix restrictions. But if you are doing it, then its good :)

Comment: Another think to consider would be postfix `authorized_submit_users` - http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#authorized_submit_users. It's probably not clever idea to have PHP `mail()` available globally but anyway... (On OpenBSD as PHP is chrooted by default, `mail()` won't work and `femail-chroot` package forwards mail via PHP `mail()` over network... Thus another issue - `$mynetworks` :)

Comment: So I ended for now with second instance of postfix submission process which uses default postfix `smtpd_sasl_path`, ie. via Cyrus SASL library and I'm using auxprop/sasldb as DB for credentials, I also restrict which MAIL FROM is allowed for an authenticated user via `smtpd_sender_login_maps`. But I'm still not happy, I need to solve problem with SSL cert verification ;)